# Port forwarding Terraria local server to linux VPS

Tags: tcp, udp, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

Terraria uses both TCP and UDP for the same port. I have a linux VPS.

Terraria server is listening on my local windows PC on port 7777 (UDP & TCP).

I need to port forward my local terraria server to my linux vps, so my friends can join the terraria server from my linux vps IP address.

How can I achieve that? Is there any software that can do this, both on the windows and the linux side?